# check if field value has changed with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to conastantly check if the value changes.. So if the user selects a new value in an input form I want to run some js code..

```
<div class="select2-container country_to_state country_select" id="s2id_billing_country" style="width: 100%;">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="select2-choice" tabindex="-1">
        <span class="select2-chosen" id="select2-chosen-1">Schweiz</span>
        <abbr class="select2-search-choice-close" />
        <span class="select2-arrow" role="presentation">
    <b role="presentation"/>
    </span>
    </a>
    <label for="s2id_autogen1" class="select2-offscreen">Land *</label>
    <input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen" type="text" aria-haspopup="true" role="button" aria-labelledby="select2-chosen-1" id="s2id_autogen1" />
</div>
<select name="billing_country" id="billing_country" class="country_to_state country_select " tabindex="-1" title="Land *" style="display: none;">
    <option value="">Land auswählen…</option>
    <option value="DE" selected="selected">Deutschland</option>
    <option value="CH">Schweiz</option>
    <option value="AT">Österreich</option>
</select>
```

I've tried this so far (doesn't work)

```
$('#select2-chosen-1').change(function() {
    alert("change");
});
```

Comment: I think same id issue. You can change id

Comment: `So if the user selects a new value in an input form` But you have posted HTML markup relevant to `span` elements, not `input`. So if this is your relevant HTML markup, how do you change `span` content?

Comment: Please check if onchange event exists for span,

Comment: updated the question with the whole form code

Answer (score 1):

First off you should never have 2 elements with the same ID on a page.  Use classes instead

```
<span class="select2-chosen">Value 1</span>
<span class="select2-chosen">Value 2</span>

$('input').on('change', '.select2-chosen', (function() 
{
     alert("change");
 });
```

Here we have had to implement the delegated event listener for the input's which get dynamically generated by `select2` after page instantiation.  Then we listen to it's `change` event and `alert`.

Alternatively, give your `<input class="select2-focusser select2-offscreen"` and `<select name="billing_country"..` a class of `someClass` and listen to the change

```
$('.someClass').change(function() 
{
    alert("change");
});
```

Comment: There is no default event `onchange` for `span` element

Comment: Wait, maybe wrong HTML markup posted in question because OP was talking about `input`, so not sure what to expect :)

Comment: @A.Wolff Have posted update solution regarding specific `select2` behaviour.

Comment: I can't change the code unfortunately.. just work with what I have.. So which code will work for that?

Comment: Unfortunately the code you have now added is once the `select2` has been initiated.  It looks like the target is `"#billing_country"` so you would run this javascript code `$("#billing_country").select2().on("change", function (e) {
    // mostly used event, fired to the original element when the value changes
    console.log("change val=" + e.val);
})` Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/LLw3erva/1/

Comment: I will have a closer look at it again.. but thank you!

Comment: Please then show us a demo or the page or the original code or your entire HTML or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying all the inputs within instead:

```
$('.select2-chosen').find(':input').change(function() 
{
 alert("change");
 });
```

hope this helps